# Passing space contained values as option to perl

Tags: perl

Space ignorance issue, when passing perl script with option(space contained value) as argument.

## test.pl

```
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my $option;
GetOptions(
 "myreg=s"=>\$option,
);

print "Option: $option\n";
```

I have a shell script and when I pass the perl script with option (space contained value) the script print only the option value before to the space.

```
/my/test/script.sh /my/testing/test.pl --myreg='Reg 1'
```

The above execution prints,

```
Option: Reg
```

What the issue? Please assist.

Comment: Shell interpolation and quoting. Your quotes are getting 'parsed' by the shell before being handed to perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of improper escaping performed by `/my/test/script.sh`, something along the lines of doing `$@` or `exec $@` instead of `"$@"` or `exec "$@"`.

```
$ cat ./bad
#!/bin/sh
exec $@

$ ./bad ./test --myreg='Reg 1'
Option: Reg

$ cat ./good
#!/bin/sh
exec "$@"

$ ./good ./test --myreg='Reg 1'
Option: Reg 1
```